# Oracle SQL Developer(4.0.0.12)

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

First time posting here, hopes it goes well.

I try to make a query with Oracle SQL Developer, where it returns a customer_ID from a table and the time of the payment from another. I'm pretty sure that the problems lies within my logicflow (It was a long time I used SQL, and it was back in school so I'm a bit rusty in it). I wanted to list the IDs as DISTINCT and ORDER BY the dates ASCENDING, so only the first date would show up.

However the returned table contains the same ID's twice or even more in some cases. I even found the same ID and same DATE a few times while I was scrolling through it.

If you would like to know more please ask!

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    FIRM.customer.CUSTOMER_ID,
    FIRM.account_recharge.X__INSDATE FELTOLTES
FROM
    FIRM.customer
        INNER JOIN FIRM.account
        ON FIRM.customer.CUSTOMER_ID = FIRM.account.CUSTOMER
            INNER JOIN FIRM.account_recharge
            ON FIRM.account.ACCOUNT_ID = FIRM.account_recharge.ACCOUNT
WHERE
    FIRM.account_recharge.X__INSDATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('14-01-01', 'YY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE('14-12-31', 'YY-MM-DD')
ORDER
    BY FELTOLTES
```

Comment: `Distinct` is applied to all the columns in the select list. See my answer.

Comment: Thank you guys! both of your solutions worked as intended! (I thought that I miss something very elementary...) Can't upvote yet, so I can only say thanks, again :) (Can't I mark this question as answered somehow?)

Comment: Ohh I found it out how, sorry Edit:can't mark both of them, so I marked the one I ended up using, but both works

Comment: I tried to upvote, but I need 15 rep for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your select works like this because a `CUSTOMER_ID` indeed has more than one `X__INSDATE`, therefore the records in the result will be distinct. If you need only the first date then don't use `DISTINCT` and `ORDER BY` but try to select for `MIN(X__INSDATE)` and use `GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID`.

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT DISTINCT FIRM.customer.CUSTOMER_ID,
>     FIRM.account_recharge.X__INSDATE FELTOLTES

Distinct is applied to both the columns together, which means you will get a distinct **ROW** for the **set of values** from the two columns. So, basically the distinct refers to all the columns in the select list.

It is equivalent to a select without distinct but a group by clause.

It means,

`select distinct a, b....`

is equivalent to,

`select a, b...group by a, b`

If you want the desired output, then **CONCATENATE** the columns. The distict will then work on the single concatenated resultset.